# How can I get a list of responses from CheckBoxes into a 1d array?

Tags: google-apps-script

When I get the responses of CheckBoxes they are in a 2d array format.  I would like to convert it to a 1d format.

Another way I could ask this is using App Script how can I easily convert a 2d array into a 1d array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through each member of the nested arrays, and push to a new array.

```
var twoD = [['a', 'b'],['c','d'],['e','f']];
var oneD = [];
for (var i in twoD){
  for (var q in twoD[i]){
    oneD.push(twoD[i][q]);
  }
}
```